# Messenger with webcam support for linux

Tags: linux

I am in search of a messenger client that supports webcam on linux, does one exist? I tried pidgin and looked through addons for it but couldn't find one. I am using Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 3):

[aMSN](http://www.amsn-project.net/) has full webcam support, it's free and open source.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think they are all crap. Not very stable, not documented well, no meaningful error messages... But if you must, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software#Free_software Just don't say I didn't warn you. Also, there's skype for linux and aMSN might or might not work, too.

Answer (score -1):

[Kopete](http://kopete.kde.org/), it has webcam support for Yahoo and MSN